# creating data-frame from pipe & comma delimited file

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to create  data-frame form a data feed which has the following format,

```
ABC,13:10,23| PQR,01:20,2| XYZ,07:30,14  
BCD,11:40,13| ABC,05:50,9| RST,17:20,5
```

Each record is pipe delimited and comes in batch of 3 and consists of 3 sub records.

I intend to have each sub record as a column and each record aa one row of the data frame.So the above would result in 3 columns and 9 rows.

```
col1    col2     col3 
ABC     13:10     23
PQR     01:20      2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode    
df = spark.read.text("/path/to/data.csv")
df.select(explode(split(df["value"], "\|"))).show()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.